# Unable to extend my linkedin profile in career 2.0

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs

I have complete sign up  but there should not connect following my profile

```
Stack Overflow
GitHub
CodePlex
LinkedIn
```

So, How to get or import my linked in or stack Overflow profile in career 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an invitation in order to be able to create a profile and it looks like none is associated with your account. [You can request one here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one).